# How to load configMap and secret from aws into application.yaml in spring project

Tags: java, spring, kubernetes, aws-secrets-manager

Now. i use spring.config.import for load secret from aws secret and use spring.cloud.kubernetes for load content in configMap. But when run application the spring not automatically load secret it use all content in configMap. this my code

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - optional:aws-secretsmanager:/api-secrets/demo
  cloud:
    kubernetes:
      enabled: true
      reload:
        enabled: true
        mode: event
      config:
        enabled: true
        name: demo-configmap
        namespace: demo-name
        sources:
          - name: content-application
        enableVersioning: true
```

i want to load content from configMap and auto load secret from aws secret. what can i do?

Comment: is your requirement is to load secret and configmap into your spring app separately?    converst secret data into configmap and load config map into your spring application